# Associate custom uri schemes with Java self contained application for windows

Tags: java, windows, javafx, custom-url

I have a self contained JavaFX application. For an improved user experience, I would like the user to click on a button/link on the browser and start the application. Just like magnet URI for torrent, the link contains metadata that is required to start up the application.

Is there a way to generate the executable for JavaFX application to associate with custom URI just like magnet URIs associated with torrent applications.

Comment: Have you looked at [tag:java-web-start]?

Comment: Yes, Java Web Start is the answer.  Tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Comment: I am currently using JWS, it requires the user to download the jnlp file. And then double click to start the application. Custom URI association improves the user experience. Just like in mobile devices the applications can be directly launched from the browser.

Comment: You need to add the custom URI to your windows registry. That's quite simple, just google it. Then, when your app starts, you'll fetch the params using the args var from you main method of your mainApp. That's how, for windows, you'll enable your app to start clicking on a link like myApp://

Comment: Can it be done during installation? I know JavaFX self contained application can add file association to windows registry, I am not sure how it does it.

Comment: I believe that if you package a Java Web Start application using the `-embedjnlp` option as discussed in the Oracle documentation [Performance Tuning for Web Deployment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABCJCHH), then the user is not required to "download the jnlp file. And then double click to start the application".  Instead the Java Web Start application could be directly launched by a user click (or JavaScript autoclick) on a web page. *Disclaimer: I have not used Java Web Start in a long time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to associate custom URIs with an application.

I already have a task that generates the native bundles.

First step is to enable verbose in your ant task so you can locate the build path. 
As mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#A1308687), in 6.3.3 enable verbose and look for `<AppName>.iss` file in the build directory, which is usuablly `AppData/Local/Temp/fxbundler*`.

Make sure you have the directory that contains package directory in the classpath. Here is an example of how you can add that to the classpath:

```
<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml" uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant" classpath="${build.src.dir}:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ant-javafx.jar"/>
```

In my example I have package/windows with Drop-In Resources in src directory.

If you have file association, you will see something like this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCR; Subkey: ".txt"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "AppNameFile"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

Just after this line you can add lines to add custom URI's registry entries.

If you don't have file association then you will add entries after

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=ARCHITECTURE_BIT_MODE
```

You can find the template of how AppName.iss file is generated at this location:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\ant-javafx.jar\com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\template.iss`

[Here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_registrysection.htm) you will find **how** to write lines like the one above

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx) you can find **what** registry keys and entries that needs to be added for custom URI association.

Comment: hi @mo3z, your answer is specific to windows do you have any idea for mac os?

Comment: I'm able to implement the custom URI scheme but I'm not able to get the link details in the application for example if I have a URI like this: `schema://parameter/value` how will i get the parameter & it's value in the callback function within the javafx app ?