# JavaFX Application Custom Scheme URI Handler

Tags: java, javafx, url-scheme

I have created a JavaFX Application which can be open using a custom scheme `myscheme://argument1/argument2`

I have successfully implemented the `info.plist` file which has the following content:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>


<array>
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>com.myapp.Main</string>
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
          <string>myscheme</string> // <-- this is the scheme which can open the application
       </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

Now after this i'm successfully able to open my application using archor tag in the html page

`<a href="scheme://argument1">Open App</a>`

The problem I'm facing is related to the argument, My question is very simple how can I receive arguments in a callback within my application. Right now my main class looks like this:

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layouts/main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle(title);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, screenSize.getWidth() / 2, screenSize.getHeight() / 2));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have also tried googling it but couldn't find my answer any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking for [`Application#getParameters()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters())? Also, instead of using `Toolkit` to get the screen dimensions you can use the JavaFX API for the same: [`Screen`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html).

Comment: @Slaw thanks for your comment but looking at the `getParameter` method docs it says "Retrieves the parameters for this Application, including any arguments passed on the command line." I guess i won't work for custom schemes?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the mechanism you're using, so I don't quite understand what you need exactly. Is your application _launched_ with the arguments passed to it? If so, then the arguments will be passed to `main(String[] args)` which you then pass to JavaFX via `launch(args)`. Those arguments are accessible using `#getParameters()`. Or are you looking for something different?

Comment: have you heard the concept of deep linking? it something like this: http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/deep-linking-using-custom-url-scheme/ but in my case i'm using javafx application, which can be opened using the custom scheme with arguments as well for example: scheme://argument1/argument2

Comment: In general I'm familiar with the concept, but not necessarily in the context you're using it. From what I can gather by your question, you appear to be using iOS or macOS. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with either environment. Nor am I familiar with Swift. I recommend first figuring out _how the arguments are passed to the application_. That can give a hint regarding how to move forward. In the meantime, hopefully someone who knows more than I do comes along and can provide a solution.

Comment: as per your comment "you appear to be using iOS or macOS" the link i shared above was to just give you an idea what i'm trying to do, i need to open my application from browser window using a link `schema://argument1/argument` the problem i'm facing that i'm not getting the value from the uri

Comment: @Slaw check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505471/associate-custom-uri-schemes-with-java-self-contained-application-for-windows